# In Python find and extract only required info

Tags: python

I am getting info from an HP device and storing it in a variable named `data`.

Now, I want to extract only the values for `Chassis:` and `Serial Number:` from the output, an example of which is below (I obtain it by typing the command `show module`):

```
============================
coaza077-cor-01> show module

 Status and Counters - Module Information
  Chassis: 2900-24G J9049A         Serial Number:   SG748KI09F
  Slot  Module Description                       Serial Number
  ----- ---------------------------------------- --------------

coaza077-cor-01> exit
Do you want to log out [y/n]? y
=============================
```

The code below is my attempt to do this:

```
    sList = os.linesep.join([s for s in data.splitlines() if s])


for i in range(0,len(sList)):

    if (sList[i].lower()).find('Chassis') >= 0:
        #DEVICE PROCESSOR
        device_processor= _parse.getdata(sList[i].lower(), 'Chassis:', ' ')
        if debugging == "_HP2900" or debugging == "ALL": print "_HP2900.py", "Processor", device_processor          

    if (sList[i].lower()).find('Serial Number') >= 0:
        print 'Serial Number'
        #DEVICE SERIAL NUMBER
        device_serial= (_parse.serial_number(sList[i].lower()[len('Serial Number'):])).upper()
        if debugging == "_HP2900" or debugging == "ALL": print "_HP2900.py", "Serial", device_serial
```

.. however I can't seem to get only the two values that I need. I'm new to Python, and not sure that I'm even approaching the problem correctly.

How can I get just the fields that I need?

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error? Or is the result not what you expect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> data = """
============================
coaza077-cor-01> show module

 Status and Counters - Module Information
  Chassis: 2900-24G J9049A         Serial Number:   SG748KI09F
  Slot  Module Description                       Serial Number
  ----- ---------------------------------------- --------------

coaza077-cor-01> exit
Do you want to log out [y/n]? y
=============================
"""
>>> chasis = data.split('Chassis:')[1].split('Serial')[0].strip()
>>> serial = data.split('Serial Number:')[1].split()[0].strip()
>>> 
>>> print chasis
2900-24G J9049A
>>> print serial
SG748KI09F
```

Update for comment:

```
>>> x, y = chasis.split()
>>> print x
2900-24G
>>> print y
J9049A
```

Comment: Hi it worked. thanks.. In chasis:2900-24G J9049A  I want break this and store like in 2 vriables chasis:2900-24G and Number J9049A . how to do ..

Comment: I am new to python.. Thank you develerx.. Awesome.. take care

Answer (score 1):

First few things.

Why do you first split data into lines and then join them into string? Your iteration goes through each sign, not each letter.

What is _parse? Please, paste all needed code if you want help.

`sList[i].lower()).find('Chassis')` How do you want to find word "Chasis" in all-lowered text? Remember, that find is not case independant.

Little more pythonic:

```
for line in data.splitlines():
    if "Chassis" in line:
        print line
        #DEVICE PROCESSOR
        #device_processor= _parse.getdata(sList[i].lower(), 'Chassis:', ' ')
        #if debugging == "_HP2900" or debugging == "ALL": print "_HP2900.py", "Processor", device_processor          

    if 'Serial Number' in line:
        print line
        #DEVICE SERIAL NUMBER
        #device_serial= (_parse.serial_number(sList[i].lower()[len('Serial Number'):])).upper()
        #if debugging == "_HP2900" or debugging == "ALL": print "_HP2900.py", "Serial", device_serial
```

Where data is all your text. Try to read something more about pythonic ways to make your life easier ;)

What the script does now is finding the correct lines. When you write what `_parse` is, I can add something more to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working since you first updating your current row to lower case and then trying to find string that has mixed upper/lower case. So all that you need is to remove .lower().

Try this:

```
for row in (line.strip() for line in data.split('\n') if line.strip()):

    rData = row.split() # just for sample

    if 'Chassis' in row:
        #DEVICE PROCESSOR
        chassisInd = rData.index('Chassis:')
        if chassisInd + 1 < len(rData):
            print 'Chassis:', rData[chassisInd + 1]

    if 'Serial Number' in row:
        serialInd = rData.index('Serial Number:')
        if serialInd + 1 < len(rData):
            print 'Serial Number:', rData[serialInd + 1]
```